# Defining multiple cases for an Ansible variable based on multiple conditions

Tags: variables, ansible, conditional-statements, case

I have this variable here, set in a .yaml variables file

```yaml
patch_plan: 'foo-{{ patch_plan_week_and_day }}-bar'
```

I want my `patch_plan_week_and_day` variable to be set dynamically, based on `role` **and** `environment` which are 2 other variables set elsewhere (doesn't matter now) outside this variables file.

For instance, I will explain 3 cases:

- If `role = 'master'` and `environment = 'srvb'` then `patch_plan_week_and_day = 'Week1_Monday'` and thus the end result of `patch_plan = 'foo-Week1_Monday-bar'`.
- If `role != 'master'` and `environment = 'srvb'` then `patch_plan_week_and_day = 'Week1_Tuesday'` and thus the end result of `patch_plan = 'foo-Week1_Tuesday-bar'`
- If `role = 'slave'` and `environment = 'pro'` then `patch_plan_week_and_day = 'Week3_Wednesday'` and hus the end result of `patch_plan = 'foo-Week3_Wednesday-bar'`

This is the idea of the code:

```yaml
patch_plan: 'foo-{{ patch_plan_week_and_day }}-bar'

# Patch Plans
## I want something like this:

# case 1
patch_plan_week_and_day: Week1_Monday
when: role == 'master' and environment == 'srvb'

# case 2
patch_plan_week_and_day: Week1_Tuesday
when: role != 'master' and environment == 'srvb'

# case 3
patch_plan_week_and_day: Week3_Wednesday
when: role == 'slave' and environment == 'pro'
```

I have 14 cases in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, this is what fixed it, thank you everyone

```
patch_plan: 'foo-{{ patch_plan_week_and_day[environment][role] }}-bar'

srvb:
  master: Week1_Monday
  slave: Week1_Tuesday
pre:
  master: Week1_Sunday
  slave: Week1_Friday
pro:
  master: Week1_Thursday
  slave: Week1_Wednesday
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the logic into a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
  patch_plan_week_and_day_dict:
    srvb:
      master: Week1_Monday
      default: Week1_Tuesday
    pro:
      slave: Week3_Wednesday
      default: WeekX_Wednesday
```

Create the project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    ├── master
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    ├── non_master
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    └── slave
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml

10 directories, 9 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```bash
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    patch_plan_week_and_day_dict:
      srvb:
        master: Week1_Monday
        default: Week1_Tuesday
      pro:
        slave: Week3_Wednesday
        default: WeekX_Wednesday
  roles:
    - "{{ my_role }}"
```

The code of all roles is identical

```yaml
shell> cat roles/master/defaults/main.yml 
patch_plan_role: "{{ (my_role in patch_plan_week_and_day_dict[env].keys()|list)|
                     ternary(my_role, 'default') }}"
patch_plan_week_and_day: "{{ patch_plan_week_and_day_dict[env][patch_plan_role] }}"

shell> cat roles/master/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: patch_plan_week_and_day
```

Example 1.

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e env=srvb -e my_role=master
  ...
  patch_plan_week_and_day: Week1_Monday
```

Example 2.

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e env=srvb -e my_role=non_master
  ...
  patch_plan_week_and_day: Week1_Tuesday
```

Example 3.

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e env=pro -e my_role=slave
  ...
  patch_plan_week_and_day: Week3_Wednesday
```